# Calculated Column using current year (Today)

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, date

I need to create a calculated column that would need to show the years since a document was published. Notice that I'm not saying [Created]. The issue is that I have a document library where our office staff upload documents. One of the required columns called "Year Published" (Number). The calculated column would calculate the difference. I tried `[Year Published] - Year([Today])`, but that fails as the error message I get says... *"Calculated columns cannot contain volatile functions like Today and Me"*.

Any suggestion here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround, you could create a date and time column called Today with Today's date as default value. Then use following formula in the calculated column.

[Year Published] - Year([Today])

[image]